# Finding config.rb used by Sencha Cmd

Tags: css, extjs, sass, sencha-touch, compass

I am trying to configure my Sencha Touch 2 application build process such that linked fonts have correct path in the CSS.

I have added `fonts_path` to `MyApp/resources/sass/config.rb`:

```
# Get the directory that this configuration file exists in
dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)

# Load the sencha-touch framework automatically.
load File.join(dir, '..', '..', 'touch', 'resources', 'themes')

# Compass configurations
sass_path = dir
css_path = File.join(dir, "..", "css")
fonts_path = File.join(dir, "..", "fonts")

# Require any additional compass plugins here.
images_dir = File.join(dir, "..", "images")
output_style = :compressed
environment = :production
```

which should change the fonts path used in the SCSS:

```
@include icon-font('Pictos', font-files('pictos-web.svg', 'pictos-web.eot'));
```

but this still compiles to

```
@font-face{font-family:"Pictos";src:url('/stylesheets/fonts/pictos-web.svg') format('svg'),url('/stylesheets/fonts/pictos-web.eot') format('embedded-opentype')}
```

So the fonts path used in is the CSS still is `/stylesheets/fonts/`, and I don't know why.

I have tried to find the config.rb used by calling `sencha -d app build production`, but this does not give me any more details as to the config file used:

```
[INF] -compass-compile-sass-dir:
ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x64-mingw32]
[DBG] exit code was : 0
[DBG] exit code was : 0
[DBG] ruby detected, checking for version in : ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x64-mingw32]

[DBG] setting GEM_HOME to C:\Users\urban\bin\Sencha\Cmd\6.0.1.76\extensions\sencha-compass\gems
[INF] executing compass using system installed ruby runtime
[DBG] executing compass : ruby C:\Users\urban\bin\Sencha\Cmd\6.0.1.76\extensions\sencha-compass\gems\bin\compass compile --force --trace
identical ../css/app.css 
[DBG] exit code was : 0
```

Now I am not sure that I edited the correct config.rb, there are quite some:

```
MyApp/resources/sass/config.rb
MyApp/touch/packages/sencha-touch-grid/examples/grid/resources/sass/config.rb
MyApp/touch/packages/sencha-touch-grid/examples/summarygrid/resources/sass/config.rb
MyApp/.backup/MyApp/2.3.1.410/resources/sass/config.rb
MyApp/touch/resources/sass/config-debug.rb
MyApp/touch/resources/sass/config.rb
MyApp/touch/resources/themes/vendor/config/compass-recipes/config.rb
```

Which one is it or is it neither?

Comment: Do you know the exact command Sencha uses to compile Compass with and where it runs the command from?

Comment: From what I found in the debug (see above), I guess it is `ruby C:\Users\urban\bin\Sencha\Cmd\6.0.1.76\extensions\sencha-compass\gems\bin\compass compile --force --trace`.

Comment: Ok, so since it isn't trying to compile a specific directory, you just need to figure out where the command is being run from.  Once you figure that out, that will tell you which config.rb is the correct one (because it will be in the same directory).  I don't know Sencha, so I can't really help there.

Comment: I have found that I was in the correct config.rb, I just had to set `http_fonts_path`, not `fonts_path`.